# how to add/get a new plugin service like inAppBillingService, in an existing java eclipse project with gluon

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, gluon, gluon-mobile, javafxports

At the beginning of the project, I had already installed some services like magnetometer and accelerometer.

Now, I want to connect my application to the Google Play by using the InAppBilling service. But I don't know to connect this new plugin with my eclipse project. I have checked that, by adding, in build.gradle file, the plugin 'vibration' in its jfxmobile - downconfig section. Gradle fetches the new service 'vibration'. And I use the same way for adding 'inAppBilling'

Perhaps, concerning the inAppBilling plugin, is it a problem of versions ?

```
I use
jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.8
com.gluonhq:charm:4.3.0
javafxportsVersion = '8.60.9'
downConfig {version '3.5.0'
```

---

After an additional analysis, I have solved te problem: it was a problem of name. Write 'in-app-billing' instead of 'inappbilling' in the build.gradle file, as follows:

```
jfxmobile {
     javafxportsVersion = '8.60.9'
     downConfig {
        version '3.5.0'
        plugins 'accelerometer', 'device', 'storage', 'display', 'in-app-billing'
    }
```

Note that I have also modified the gluonhq.charm version from 4.3.0 to 5.0.0, as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0'
}
```

***With this new compiler version, the performance of the executable is better or not?***

Thanks

Comment: If you have the Gluon plugin for your IDE, there is a context menu option that lets you pick Charm Down services easily, no need for typing. See this [doc](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/5.0.0/#_gluon_mobile_settings). About version numbers, you should always try to use the latest. So far: jfxmobile-plugin: 1.3.13, Charm 5.0.0, Charm-Down 3.8.0. Performance won't be different, but you will benefit from several fixes and improvements.

Comment: ok, thanks for your info